# Parallelization over user defined types with destructive function in Julia

Tags: julia

I have the following code:

```
mutable struct T
    a::Vector{Int}
end

N = 100
len = 10
Ts = [T(fill(i, len)) for i in 1:N]

for i = 1:N
   destructive_function!(Ts[i])
end
```

`destructive_function!` changes `a` in each element of `Ts`.

Is there any way to parallelize the `for` loop? `SharedArray` does not seem available for user-defined types.

Comment: You don't need to use `SharedArray`s to parallelize. In fact, reducing the amount of communication is usually helpful (in any language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it would be simpler to use threads rather than processes to parallelize the loop

```
Threads.@threads for i = 1:N
   destructive_function!(Ts[i])
end
```

Just make sure that you set `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` environment variable before starting Julia. You can check number of threads running with `Threads.nthreads()` function.

If you want to use processes rather than threads then probably it is simplest to make `destructive_function!` return the modified value and then run `pmap(destructive_function!, Ts)` to collect the modified values in a new array (but this would not modify the `Ts` in place).

Comment: Thank you! How can I decide which one I should use?

Comment: This is a broad topic unfortunately. Here are excellent slides http://slides.com/valentinchuravy/julia-parallelism#/ that will give you some guidelines. My experience is that multiple processing is simpler to use (less error prone), but will be slower if you would have to move a lot of data between processes.